# PHP Mysql concurrent

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I am recently coding PHP with mysql. I have a problem with concurreny with Mysql
For example , if I got a result set from mysql like 
 $result = $data -> where("id > 5");

and meanwhile another page submit a query like "delete table ...".

Are there any data in $result which I have already got before?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is.

But if you set $result with data from the DB and then delete the corresponding data in the DB while the PHP code is still running, it will still be in the variable. But if you do another request to the DB it will not find it anymore.

Comment: i mean, I think $result is like a pointer. thus we always fetch data use code like 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
// process the row...
}

If I totally have 20,000 item and I have already processed 10,000 items. 
Then at the same time , another page send an query to the mysql database to clear the table ..Are there still any data in result(another 10,000 items that I have not processed)?